# TypeScript: Factory function for union types

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, factory, union-types, typescript-types

I have a custom `Factory` type that lets me create factory functions.

```
export type Factory<T> = (state?: Partial<T>) => T;
```

I have an `<Avatar />` React component that has a union type as prop because there can be two versions of it (just the image, or clickable image). In other words, the component can have either or props.

```
type AvatarOnlyProps = {
  alt: string;
  src: string;
};

type ClickableAvatarProps = {
  alt: string;
  label: string;
  onClick:
    | ((event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>) => void)
    | undefined;
  src: string;
};

export type AvatarProps = AvatarOnlyProps | ClickableAvatarProps;
```

I want to create a factory function for the avatar's props. I tried typing it like this:

```
const createProps: Factory<AvatarProps> = ({
  alt = 'Your avatar',
  label,
  onClick,
  src: source = '/images/default-avatar.png',
} = {}) => ({ alt, label, onClick, src: source });
```

But TypeScript complains:

```
Property 'label' does not exist on type 'Partial<AvatarOnlyProps> | Partial<ClickableAvatarProps>'.
```

in the arguments of the factory function.

[image]

How can I make the error go away? How can I get TypeScript to under stand, that in this factory function either both `onClick` and `label` will be supplied, or neither?

Comment: `label` doesn't exist on `AvatarOnlyProps`, so the attempt to destructure the parameter results in the compiler complaint. You'll need to use [type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types) to resolve the input parameter type before attempting to access properties defined against those types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve it for my use case by creating the factor function with the minimal keys populated:

```
const createProps: Factory<AvatarProps> = ({
  alt = 'Your avatar',
  src: source = '/images/default-avatar.png',
  ...props
} = {}) => ({
  alt,
  src: source,
  ...props,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't destructure a property from a union unless it is included on all members of the union.  `label` and `onClick` don't have any definition on `AvatarOnlyProps`.

> How can I get TypeScript to under stand, that in this factory function either both onClick and label will be supplied, or neither?

Based on how you've described your `Factory`, it isn't actually the case that you have both or neither.  A `Factory` of `T` takes an incomplete `Partial<T>` and returns a complete `T`.  Since it accepts `Partial<T>` it seems like it could accept a `Partial<ClickableAvatarProps>` which has `label` but not `onClick`, or vice-versa.

You are setting default values for `alt` and `src`, but not for `label` or `onClick`.  So if only one is supplied then only one will be returned too.

In order to properly describe this behavior, we need more than just the union of two possibilities.  `createProps` accepts an object with all four properties where all are optional.  It returns an object with all four property keys where `alt` and `src` will always be `string`, but `label` and `onClick` might be `undefined`.

We need to define that returned object.  Here's one way:

```
type AvatarProps = AvatarOnlyProps & Partial<ClickableAvatarProps>;
```

You can now define `createProps` as `Factory<AvatarProps>` and you won't have any issues.